# Best video format/codec/technique to send small video with syncronization

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a strange task to solve. We have a small-sized video window (like 300x200 pixels, 256-colors palette) and 44kHz 2ch sound playing on server. We need to send this stream video to some clients (1,2.. up to 10). Strict requirements is syncronization (we should have video syncronized as precise as 20 ms on all clients) and loss-less (preferrably no losses at all, but it is discussable).

Please recommend any good video format/codec/linux software to install on server to make this thing possible. Thanks!

Comment: H264/AAC/MP4 ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want the videos to be syncronized with? Do you want to syncronize all the videos on all the clients with each other? In that case no codec/format will help you. You have to design your own protocol and keep the clients syncronized yourself. For example: you can count on all the clocks of the clients to be syncronized and use it to syncronize your video. This approach will probably syncronize the videos within 1s boundary. 20ms looks unrealistic to me because a typical video has 24 fps that makes ~40ms duration for a single frame.

What do you meen "loss-less"? All modern video codecs (h264, vp9, etc) are lossy. But they actually do a very good job of compressing the video and making it look almost indistinguishable from a lossless version.

Comment: Well, I want a simulation program work on the server side and send resulting video to all clients who need to see it. At the same time it should be interactive, it means connected clients (at least one or two) should be able to send key presses and/or mouse moves to simulation program to change parameters. It is quite dynamic thats why delay should be not more than 20ms.